# Can Sharepoint show different versions of a page based on the URL?

Tags: sharepoint

We currently have Sharepoint installed for our Intranet. We use ISA Server to expose it to the outside for certain users. These two access points use different domain names.

The problem is that we have a links page that has links to other systems that we do NOT expose to the outside world. So when users click on these links when accessing from the outside, they get 404 errors.

What I'd like to do is present my outside users with a different links page depending on whether they access the portal from the outside, or internally.

Is this possible?

Just to clarify, it's the same group of users logging in from both inside and outside. I want to filter content based on the entry point to the portal, not the user or group.

Answer (score 2):

We accomplish that using user groups. Depending on who you login as, say "Outside Vendor" then you wouldn't see other department's items, such as "Customer Service Tools" etc...

I suggest you make an Outside group and customize the sharepoint site permissions to show them only what you want them to see.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using Audiences, if you're running MOSS. Audiences use user profile data to allow SharePoint to target specific content to specific groups of users. The upside is that you may be able to create your audiences based on data that's already in your user profiles or AD, rather than manually maintain the membership of user groups.

MVP Sahil Malik has a nice writeup on Audiences and how to configure them: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/sortinganditerating/article.php/c13255__2/

John

Comment: Thanks. I had thought about audiences, but the problem is that the same people will be accessing from inside and outside. So how do I segment them out? It's really the URL I want to filter on, not the user, and that's where I'm hitting a brick wall.